# Robot Framework Stubborn "Element did not appear in 5 seconds" error

Tags: frameworks, robotframework

I'm writing up a Robot Framework script to fill out a form. Simple script, using a small dictionary, all the rest of it is working but I can't seem to interact with this certain field. I've tried almost a dozen ways to interact with the element, but none of them are working. Can you guys help me out here?  Here's my code.

```
Documentation       Frevvo Form
Library             Zoomba.GUILibrary
Library             Process
Resource            ../../Pages/resource.robot
Suite Setup         Browser Setup       ${url}  ${browser}

*** Keywords ***

Student Form Data
    [Arguments]      ${Frevvo}
    Run Keyword If  '${Frevvo}[TulaneID]'!='${EMPTY}'  Wait For And Input Text  ${TulaneID}  ${Frevvo}[TulaneID]
    Run Keyword If  '${Frevvo}[Term]'!='${EMPTY}'  Wait For And Input Text  ${Term}  ${Frevvo}[Term]

*** Variables ***

${TulaneID}  //*[contains(name(),'TulaneID')]

[already tried the below - no success]

#//input[@name='TulaneID']
#//input[@id='w11562aab5b4b2']
#//*[@id="w11562aab5b4b2"]
#//*[@name="TulaneID"]
#//*[@id="_5le4NoQ-EeyE6Z5Sq_0wTQ"]


*** Test Cases ***

TC 001 Basic Frevvo
    Set To Dictionary           ${Frevvo}           TulaneID=211003560      Term=2022 Spring
    Login
    Student Form Data           ${Frevvo}
```

And here is the HTML of the page. The element I need is in the highlighted part
[image: Highlighted Element]

Comment: Any possibility this html section is inside a frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following,

```
*** Variables ***

${TulaneID}           xpath=//input[@id='w11562aab5b4b2']
```